# How to send a txt file with json to back-end and use this

Tags: javascript, java, json, request

I looking for a solution to this..
I have a page.jsp and need to send the txt file to server and use it to read, using a Json and JavaScript.

There is my page.

```
<form:form id="formFile" name="formFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
<div class="g1" style="width: 500px;">
<label for="" class="left">Select the file:</label>
<input type="file" id="fileID" name="fileID" class=""/>
</div>
<div class="g1">
<label for="" class="left"></label>
<a class="btn" id="exportFromFile" href="#" onclick="submitFile(this);">SubmitFile</a>
</div>
</form:form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function submitFile(btn){
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileID").files[0].name;
var file = '?fileID='+ document.getElementById("fileID").files[0].name;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
  --- validation with Json and alerts}

};
xmlhttp.open("POST","submitFile.do"+file);
xmlhttp.setResquestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data ; boundary=----boundary");
xmlhttp.send(formData);
document.getElementById("fileID").value="";
};
</script>
```

Now in my Controller we have

```
@RequestMapping(value="submitFile", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "aplication/json")
@ResponseBody
public NewSolic submitNewSolic(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException{
        NewSolic validation = new NewSolic();
        String filename = request.getParameter("fileID");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         boolean isMultipart = ServetFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if(isMultipart){
               FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory():
               ServLetFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
              try{
                    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                     Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
                     StringBuffer stringValues = new StringBuffer();
                     while (iter.hasNext()){
                           FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                           if(item.getString() != null){
                           String[] itensUploadedArray = item.getString().split("\r\n");
                    for( String itemUploaded:itensUploadedArray){
                         list.add(itemUploaded);
                          -- use this list to a insert values after get all values in the txt--
                         }
                     }
                  }
           }

       }
```

The problem is in "while(iter.hasNext())", i think the file in memory not comming with data, and does not fill the StringBuffer, the file contains only numbers, but must to be in database after being read.

Comment: You can try it in a different [way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects). See the fileupload example. Or you can try to do it [without FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files)

Comment: You mean send in javascript without "send(FormData)"? Only use send()? I tried it and didn't work.

Comment: No, I mean see how they do it on the link. However I think it will be easier for you just compare your solution with the another one on the first link.

Answer (score 0):

On the link, you can see that if you want to send the whole form, you don't have to do any magic with the file, just select the whole form, put it to a FormData, and send it:

```
function submitFile(btn){
  var form = document.forms.namedItem("formFile");
  var oData = new FormData(form);
  // you can add another fields in this way
  oData.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", "submitFile.do"+file);
  oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
      alert("Uploaded!");
    } else {
      alert("Error " + oReq.status + " occurred when trying to upload your file.");
    }
  };

  oReq.send(oData);
 }
```

Please give it a try.

Comment: I try to use this code but i can't use a 'submit' in event listener, i need to use the button with tag <a class="btn">,

Comment: I update the code with this sentences and got a correct return. Thanks for helping !!